# How to create 3d carousel like www.marriott.co.uk/default.mi

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, jcarousel

I need a jquery carousel plugin like [www.marriott.co.uk/default.mi](http://www.marriott.co.uk/default.mi) site, but not found that. Can anyone suggest me , from where i can get it..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some similar carousel:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/standard

http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm